# xsl: when two nodes are equal, display child of first node

Tags: xslt, tei

I'm using XML Editor 19.1, Saxon P.E 9.7.

For each selected `div`, I'm looking to display a `graphic/@url`, following each `<surface>` if `surface/@xml:id` = `div/@facs`.

`XSL`

```
 <xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::div3[@type='col']/div4[@n]">
  <xsl:variable name="div4tablet" select="@facs"/>
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="translate(.[@n]/$div4tablet, '#', '') = preceding::facsimile/surfaceGrp[@type='tablet']/surface[@n]/@xml:id">
     <xsl:value-of select=""/> <!-- DISPLAY graphic/@url that follows facsimile/surfaceGrp/surface -->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise/>
   </xsl:choose>
  [....]
 </xsl:for-each>
```

`TEI` example

```
 <facsimile>     
  <surfaceGrp n="1" type="tablet">
   <surface n="1.1" xml:id="ktu1-2_i_1_to_10_img">
    <graphic url="../img/KTU-1-2-1-10-recto.jpg"/>
    <zone xml:id=""/>
    <zone xml:id=""/>
   </surface>
    <surface n="1.2" xml:id="ktu1-2_i_10_to_30_img">
    <graphic url="../img/KTU-1-2-10-30-recto.jpg"/>
    <zone xml:id=""/>
   </surface>
   [...]
  </surfaceGrp>
  <surfaceGrp n="2">
  [...]
  </surfaceGrp>
 </facsimile>


 <text>
  [...]
  <div3 type="col">
   <div4 n="1.2.1-10" xml:id="ktu1-2_i_1_to_10" facs="#ktu1-2_i_1_to_10_img">
    [...]
   </div4>
   <div4 n="1.2.10-30" xml:id="ktu1-2_i_10_to_30" facs="#ktu1-2_i_10_to_30_img">
    [...]
   </div4>
  </div3>
 </text>
```

I have tried `<xsl:value-of select="preceding::facsimile/surfaceGrp[@type='tablet']/surface[@n, @xml:id]/graphic/@url"/>`, but it displays all `graphic/@url` and not only the one that follows `fascsimile/surfaceGrp/surface`.
So my question: how to display only `surface/graphic/@url` for each `div3[@type='col']/div4[@n]`?

In advance, thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you use XSLT 2 or 3 and the elements have the `xml:id` attribute you do not even need a key but can use the `id` function:

```
  <xsl:template match="div4">
      <div>
          <xsl:value-of select="id(substring(@facs, 2))/graphic/@url"/>
      </div>
  </xsl:template>
```

I put the use of `id` into a template matching the `div4` element but you can of course use it the same way inside of your `for-each` selecting those elements.

See a minimal but complete sample at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpR.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks @Martin! It works great. I'll also try to apply `id` for the `zone` for each `div4/l[@n]`.

Answer (score 3):

you should use `xsl:key` for this type of problem.

First, we must declare a key for the target node

```
<xsl:key name="kSurface" match="surface" use="concat('#', @xml:id)"/>
```

notice the `concat` function being used here, an # was being added to the xml:id so that the keys would appear as:

```
#ktu1-2_i_1_to_10_img
#ktu1-2_i_10_to_30_img
```

now in this loop:

```
<xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::div3[@type='col']/div4[@n]">
```

we can access the key that matches the `@facs` attribute by having:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="key('kSurface', @facs)/graphic/@url"/>
```

The whole stylesheet is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="kSurface" match="surface" use="concat('#', @xml:id)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::div3[@type='col']/div4[@n]">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('kSurface', @facs)/graphic/@url"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

see it in action [here](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHT9).

Comment: Thank you @Joel!! Your explanation is very useful. I always have a problem with `key`. However, I think the `id` suggested by @Martin is relevant here.